# How to position a div to the bottom of the container, without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a really difficult CSS problem. I have the following layout (this is just a fast mockup in Paint):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SwxCYbJ.png]

I need to float the red box to the bottom of it's container. Normally I would use `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but that results in the text overlapping with the div, which I don't want. I want the box to behave like in the second image (same situation, but with more text)

Is this even possible? I don't mind dumping support for very old browsers.

Comment: the two footers look to be different heights, is it supposed reduce in height when there is more content or is that just a drawing issue

Comment: @PatrickEvans No, that was just a drawing issue. I did a fast sketch in Paint ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't abandon `position: absolute`.  Simply add padding to the bottom of the container equal to the height of the footer div.

```
#outer{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
}

#foot{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Without padding: http://jsfiddle.net/cG5EH/2

With padding: http://jsfiddle.net/cG5EH/1

Comment: Wow, that really pushed me into the right direction, thanks! However, this will cause the container to be 55px (in this example) longer than it would have been. Normally the page fits into the screen, but now it doesn't because it is 55px longer.
The problem is that I need to apply this to a Joomla Template and I haven't figured out yet how it sets it height...

Comment: Very simple but effective solution. Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `calc` allows you to make calculations within your css. In the example I am forcing the height to be 100% but this can be any value it could even be `height: calc(100% + 80px)`. Note the spaces around the maths operator.

see http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ for more details

```
<html>
<header>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            height:100%;
            padding-bottom: 80px;
            box-sizing: border-box; //ensures the padding is part of the 100% height.
            position:relative;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .base{
            position:absolute;
            top:calc(100% - 80px);/*80px arbitary height of the element*/
            height:80px;
            width:100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="base">
            sdfgsdfg
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```